# PlayFramework MSSQL Database error

Tags: playframework

Am trying to use MSSQL server with Play Framework, In my application.conf

```
    db.url=jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost\SQL2008:1433;DatabaseName=testDB
    db.driver=com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
    db.user=sa
    db.pass=sa
```

Am getting this below error

```
Database error
A database error occured : Cannot connected to the database, [Microsoft][SQLServer    
2000 Driver for JDBC]Error establishing socket.

play.exceptions.DatabaseException: Cannot connected to the database, [Microsoft]   
[SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC]Error establishing socket.
at play.db.DBPlugin.onApplicationStart(DBPlugin.java:132)
at play.plugins.PluginCollection.onApplicationStart(PluginCollection.java:425)
at play.Play.start(Play.java:495)
at play.Play.detectChanges(Play.java:599)
at play.Invoker$Invocation.init(Invoker.java:186)
at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC]Error    
 establishing socket.
at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseExceptions.createException(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseExceptions.getException(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseExceptions.getException(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.TDSConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerImplConnection.open(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseConnection.getNewImplConnection(Unknown Source)
```

I have added sqljdbc4.jar to lib folder.
even tried using  mssqlserver.jar,msutil.jar,msbase.jar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be useful for someone,looking for MSSQL along with play.

First download [jtds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/)

copy jtds jar file to

```
   play-1.2.3\framework\lib
```

as well as your application lib folder

restart play

In your application.conf

```
   # If you need a full JDBC configuration use the following :
   db.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/testDB;instance=SQL2008
   db.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
   db.user=sa
   db.pass=sa
```

Start Playing :)

**Update For Play2**

Add play dependencies to your `Build.scala` like this

```
 val appDependencies = Seq(
    "net.sourceforge.jtds" % "jtds" % "1.2"
  )
```

There is change in `conf` file in Play2...

```
   db.default.url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/testDB;instance=SQL2008"
   db.default.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
   db.default.user=sa
   db.default.pass=sa
```

restart play `SBT` will download dependencies for you. Start Playing :)

Comment: You should use double quotes to enclose each value of keys (e.g.: `db.default.driver="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"`)

Answer (score 0):

looks like it cannot connect to the ms sql server running on localhost:1433 port. You will probably check the following points:

1. Do you have a ms sql server running on localhost?
2. Do you have TCP/IP enabled on your ms sql server?
3. Do you have ms sql server listening to 1433 port?

You can follow http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313178 to diagnose your problem

Comment: Hi Green, Yes it is installed I do use the same mssqlserver for another JEE based applications in my machine.It happened with Play.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the SQL2008 part from your URL

```
db.url=jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=testDB
```

Comment: Hi emt,SQL2008 is instance name. There are two SQL instances running.Anyways have used jtds.

Answer (score 0):

For play framework 2.5 Following are my configurations

```
 db.default.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
 db.default.url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ipaddress:1433/TESTDB"
 db.default.username=USER
 db.default.password="Password"
 db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery="SELECT 1"
```

And added a dependency as

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    "net.sourceforge.jtds" % "jtds" % "1.2"
  )
```

Further if you are using Ebean then add ebean pluging in plugin.sbt as

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

And lastly in conf as

```
ebean.default = ["models.*"]
```