# Play! Framework 2.2.3 SQL server connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have a Play! Web-app that I am developing and I'm currently using an eBean YAML database. I have a 2008 SQL server that was set-up for me by a coworker that I'd like to connect to. I tried following another tutorial on this site 
[PlayFramework MSSQL Database error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211967/playframework-mssql-database-error)
and downloaded the jtds jar file and placed into the proper directories but I'd get an error that the driver is not found. This is my current configuration file:

```
 db.default.url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://LSA5A:1433/DatabaseName=hr_site;instance=SQL2008"
 db.default.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
 db.default.user=HUser
 db.default.password="RaeSusdaRasdh!123"
```

I have never set-up a database like this before so I'm having difficulty understanding how to set it up and how it will all works together. I didn't understand the solution from the Play! Docs for this and I'm not using MySQL so I couldn't find the help I needed online. I'm not sure what other information I need to provide but I'm running SQL server 2008, db name is SVFSSQL5A with user HRTUser and password testPass12. Thanks for your help!!

Also I have the dependency in my build file:

val appDependencies = Seq(
    "net.sourceforge.jtds" % "jtds" % "1.2"
  )

Comment: The answer in the SO link you posted has an update for play 2.x where all you need is to add a dependency to the Build.scala and update the application.conf file.  Did you try that instead?  Copying the lib over may be only for Play1.x.

Comment: Just to complement BatteryAcid comment: in case you don't have a Build.scala file add the dependency to `build.sbt` in your project root directory and then run `play update`. Or you can download the jar and place it in `<YOUR_PROJECT_DIR>/lib`.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I added the dependency to my build.sbt and fixed the formatting for the jdbc url but now it says it cannot connect to the database, so it must have found the driver now.

Comment: @dfgkljlkjsdf Make sure you have TCP enabled in SQL Server in both server and native client (see [this image](http://www.tigernews.co.uk/blog-twickers/sqlalias/02-SqlConfigManager-Protocols.png)), and that user can connect to the DB you need.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

Download the SQL-Driver for JDBC from Microsoft http://www.microsoft.com/de-DE/download/details.aspx?id=11774, install it and put the sqljdbc4.jar file in the lib folder ( \YourProject\lib).

application.conf file:

```
db.default.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver 
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\instancename:1433;databaseName=MyDBName"
db.default.user="sa"
db.default.password="MyPassword"
db.default.logStatements=true
```

Enable the TCP\IP protocoll and the port 1433 in the SQL Server Configuration Tool.

That should do the job!

Manfred

Comment: I am getting an error that it cannot find the driver. I have it in my \project\lib folder and TCP/IP is enabled, I set up the data source and the connection to the database was successful. I'm not sure why the driver is not found. I was originally using the db.default.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver but then I downloaded the driver you recommended db.default.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver